# Express the equation as a single fraction in its simplest form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Express the equation

$$ 4 - \left( (x + 3) ÷ {\frac {x² + 5x + 6}{x - 2}} \right) $$

as a single fraction in its simplest form.

So far all I managed to do was factorise the numerator to get this $$(x + 3)(x + 2)$$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: It would be nice to see your efforts here

Comment: Have you used your brackets correctly here? Missing out a set of brackets changes the expression completely.

Comment: $4-\left(x+\frac{3}{\frac{x^2+5x+6}{x}-2} \right)$

Comment: I got up to factorising the numerator: (x + 3)(x + 2)

Comment: Hi Donald, fixed the brackets; that's not the equation.

Comment: Should it be $$4-\left((x+3)\div\frac{x^2+5x+6}{x-2}\right)$$

Comment: Is this your expression $4-\frac{(x+3)}{\frac{x^2+5x+6}{x-2}}$ ?

Comment: All my paper shows is how it is written in my question

Comment: Because $(x+3)$ is a factor of that quadratic it is "morally certain" that $x+3$ was supposed to be wrapped in parens. Otherwise the keen followers of precedence rules will object and make strange noises :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well here is an answer for if the expression is as I have written it in my comment above. If my comment indeed has the wrong expression, then the steps are similar, but involves a closer look using the proper order of operations.

We first use the fact that $\frac{a}{b}\div\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a}{b}\times\frac{d}{c}$ where $b,c,d\neq 0$. This yields
$$\begin{align}4-\left((x+3)\div\frac{x^2+5x+6}{x-2}\right)&=4-\left((x+3)\times\frac{x-2}{x^2+5x+6}\right)\\&=4-\left(\frac{(x+3)(x-2)}{x^2+5x+6}\right)\end{align}$$
Now use your factorization $x^2+5x+6=(x+2)(x+3)$ and do the appropriate cancellations. Then I'll leave the rest for you to deal with.

**Recall**: $4-\frac{a}{b}=\frac{4b-a}{b}$ and $\frac{ab}{bc}=\frac{a}{c}$ if $b,c\neq 0$.

Comment: Cheers Dave, much appreciated :)